# Cannot create a tag wiki page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, tag-wiki

Hello,

I've created a number of tag wiki pages on SO before (my rep is 3.8k), and they were accepted. Since a few days when I try to create a new tag wiki I get a page with text:

> There is no tag wiki for this tag …
>   yet!
>
> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to
>   the tag. They contain an overview of
>   the topic defined by the tag, along
>   with guidelines on its usage.
>
> All registered users may propose new
>   tag wikis. Click Create Tag Wiki below
>   to get started.
>
> (Note that if you have less than 20000
>   reputation, your tag wiki will be peer
>   reviewed before it is published.)

but there is no **Create Tag Wiki** link below...

Is it a bug or I do not have permissions to create tag wikis? In the latter case a relevant message would be welcomed.

PS. I can create tag wikis on other site without any problems.

Comment: Is there a link that's labelled "Propose Tag Wiki"?

Comment: @ChrisF - No, just the text I quoted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a handful of conditions where we will stop accepting wiki edits:

1. A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the last day (absolute value) - if banned you will be banned for a week.
2. We are out of empty slots in the queue (currently 30)
3. There is an edit to a particular tag wiki that was not approved yet.

Looking through our records you fall into 1.

In particular this happened due to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11124
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11125
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11126
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11127
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/11143

It seems your peers were swamped by wiki suggested edits that were sourced from wikipedia, so they started rejecting.

I understand that sometimes it helps to source some information from wikipedia, but we much prefer original content in our wikis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - that explains it. Could I suggest a valid message is displayed on the page?