# Why is the edit button disabled?

Tags: support, faq, suggested-edits

I edited some questions before, but now I get an error message when clicking the edit button. I thought there was a problem with the specific question, but I cannot click it on *any* question.

What's going on?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: See - [Cannot create a tag wiki page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81505/cannot-create-a-tag-wiki-page) - there are some cases where the tag wiki edit button gets removed. Maybe it's the same for post edits.

Answer (score 139):

There are a handful of conditions where we will stop accepting suggested edits:

1. A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the past week (at least [5 more than one-third of your accepted edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337)).
2. We are out of empty slots in the queue. To prevent the site from being overrun with more suggested edits than available reviewers, each site has a maximum limit of edit suggestions from anyone that can be pending at any given time, and once the limit is reached, no more suggested edits will be accepted from anyone until some pending edits get reviewed. The limit is 40 on most sites, with several exceptions. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue/84398#84398) for details.
3. You have five suggested edits pending (20 on beta sites). Unlike the above limit which is site-wide and applies to the sum total of suggested edits from everyone, this limit is per-user.
4. There is a pending suggested edit to the post you're trying to edit that hasn't been reviewed yet.
5. You are not logged in and the post is less than 10 minutes old, or you are trying to edit a tag wiki.
6. You are on a child meta. (This doesn't apply to tag wikis.)
7. A moderator has banned you from suggesting edits.
8. Your account is suspended.
9. The post is locked.
10. You are editing anonymously, and one of your edits triggered our spam filter.

In most cases, you will still see the edit button, but you will get an error message if you try to click it. However, in case 5 above, no edit button will be shown, and in case 10, it will link to another page explaining that your IP address is banned. (Note: the "edit history" link there will redirect to the homepage; [this is a known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293022).)

Comment: What do the slots (2) refer to? Is the number of slots different on other sites (like some things are different on [so] from other network sites)?

Comment: @Werner I guess it's the edit suggestion review queue.

Comment: Is there any chance the limit to the edit queue will increase any time in the near future?

Comment: The edit button is greyed out for me, but I'm not getting any tooltip. I only see 1 rejected and 1 approved. I can only count 3 suggested edits. Nevermind, I can edit now.

Comment: "The mouse hover tooltip will explain why an edit cannot be suggested" -helpful

Comment: The mouse over tool tip point was really helpful !

Comment: could someone please add more links to this post on where to check these conditions (like the _check here_ links I added)?

Comment: @törzsmókus no, this is wrong edit. This site (MSE) is for ALL sites in Stack Exchange, not just for Stack Overflow. Many people here don't even have account on Stack Overflow. So pointing people to specific site is wrong, especially in official faq answers like this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh thx, my bad.

Comment: Where can I check how many suggested edits were rejected?

Comment: [Why does this question not have an "edit" button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332960/why-does-this-question-not-have-an-edit-button) - Apparently the point 4 in this answer should also be noted as having no edit button.