# Why can't I edit a question of another user?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)

This is the first time that the following happened to me:

I don't see the **Edit** button of a question asked by another user.

I only see **Link** and **Flag** buttons.

Comment: Curious. Now I see the **Edit** and **Retag** buttons after edited by another user. :?

Comment: Consider flushing your cache (ctrl-F5).  Sometimes old versions of the site scripts cause problems similar to this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you can't see the edit button for a post, it means there is already a suggested edit pending approval. Once that edit is approved, the edit button will reappear.

Of course, this does not apply if you own the post or if you have the [edit questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) privilege.

Comment: that totally makes sense with this scenario ;)

Comment: Is there a way of directly reviewing the pending edit to speed up the approval/denial process?

Answer (score -2):

It requires 2000 Reputation to edit every where. If you asked the question then you should be able to edit it as well as any answers you have posted. I can edit some of the answers of to questions I have asked but it is marked as needing moderation. Which takes time for the community to come and approve.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges

check 8th from the top.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit

Comment: I don't think so. You're able to edit questions even if you are under 2000 rep, but it wil be placed in moderation.

Comment: @oscar I see what you mean. It might be that the question has been closed. Can you past a link to the question.

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335332/how-to-wait-for-axwebbrowser-to-finish-loading, although as I said, after Jon edited it, those buttons appeared again.

Comment: @nelaar Closed questions can still be edited.

Comment: As I stated "every where", not just your own question. 
I explained that you can edit your own questions, but it goes up for moderation. .