# Missing edit link?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)

Why is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426331/how-to-check-if-a-tab-is-clicked) not editable?? It is not lock as I can see?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are many options here:

1. You are not logged on and the post is 10 minutes old or less
2. There is already a pending edit on this post
3. The queue [is full](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue), only happens rarely on new SE sites with no moderators
4. You have been banned for a week cause you submitted many rejected edits

Options 2, 3 and 4 only apply if you have less than [2,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).

Comment: And indeed: there was [a pending edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/22897).

Comment: 5. It's a site where low rep users can't edit posts. That seems to the case with several metas.