# Cannot Edit Certain Question

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing edit link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)

I clicked the `edit` link on this question only to be bounced to the 'Page Not Found' page.  When I browsed back to the question, it was still there, but without an `edit` link:
[image: Question Without edit Link]

Other questions appeared with `edit` links:
[image: Question With edit Link]

After a minute or so, the `edit` link reappeared, along with a note that another user had recently edited the question:
[image: Original Question With edit Link]

Just to clarify, does one user's edit block other edits from beginning?  Does this only happen to users with < 2,000 rep (like me)?  Is this is the FAQ or docs somewhere (I have not found it myself)?

Comment: They have pending edits - http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/595/why-are-the-edit-and-retag-links-missing-from-this-post

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, this seems to be the case.  I did not find that post before posting.  Apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: Don't apologise - duplicate are hard to find. I only knew it existed because I asked the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when you have <2k and there is a pending edit, you are blocked from editing.

As for the page not found, the edit was probably submitted between you loading the page and hitting edit.