# Why was I not able to edit this post?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing edit link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)

I was trying to edit a post on SO, which was very badly formatted. After I submitted the edit, I was redirected to the 404 page. Thinking that the owner must have removed the post while I was editing, I checked in the new queue and still was able to see the post.

The `edit` link was missing.

Is this because there were close votes or flags on the question?

Question in question: [Android Unicode characters incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8416392/561731)

Comment: If the edit link was missing it means that there were pending edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were **pending edits** and you did not have enough rep to approve or reject it.

[image: pending]