# Question Editing

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>   [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)
>   [Missing edit link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)

I am new to Stack Overflow. I saw that sometimes it allows me to edit some questions, but for some questions it is not allowing me to edit them, as there is not an "edit" link. Why is it so?

Comment: Please Sir , read the question carefully. Its not duplicate

Comment: if _it's not duplicate_ rephrase question so that I could see the difference. Thing is the way it's spelled now, is exactly as suggested edits work for me: some of my edits are accepted with +2 while others are _silently_ rejected which looks exactly as _some question it is not allowing me to edit them_

Comment: How does it not allow you to edit them? Is there no edit link? Do you get an error? Do your suggested edits seem to go through but not actually take effect? We can't read a vague question "carefully".

Comment: for some question there is not "edit" link.

Comment: A link and/or a screenshot would be helpful here. Make sure you're not looking at a locked post.

Comment: Hello @BoltClock'saUnicorn, I tried to edit the question & Post Image, but its shows me error "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: Arjun, did you try to write image URL in the comments here (I don't remember if system allows that)?

Comment: @Arjun: when that happens, just edit a plain link in (without the fancy image link syntax) saying "screenshot here: link", and someone's sure to transform that into a proper image link if it is appropriate.

Comment: @Mat,  I am not getting you.

Comment: @Arjun: if you want to post an image link, but you don't have the required rep (as you describe in one of your previous comments), just post the URL of the image as a normal link. Someone with edit privileges can then transform that into an image link easily for you. [But you have enough rep here now to do it yourself :) ]

Comment: @Mat , Got you this is a question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653540/sqlite-sqlitedase-query-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Now It is not allowing me to Edit Any Question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons why the "edit" link might not be visible to users that don't have full edit privileges on "normal" (not locked) posts:

As stated in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work):

> Suggested edits are held in a peer review queue of a fixed size. If the queue fills up, no more edit suggestions will be allowed until the queue has some empty space.

If the queue is full, the edit link does not appear for users without full edit privileges.

The other reason is if there already is a pending edit on that post. Users that can review suggested edit see a different edit link, but users without that privilege simply don't have the edit link.

(I don't know whether users that have had too many rejected suggested edits still see the link but can't submit their edits, or simply don't get the link anymore.)