# Edit link disappeared

Tags: support

I've heard of this problem before, and the suggested reasons, but I don't *think* any of them apply in this case.

According to the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link), the edit link will disappear if:

1. You are not logged on and the post is 12 hours old or less
2. There is already a pending edit on this post
3. The queue is full, only happens rarely on new SE sites with no moderators
4. You have been banned for a week cause you submitted many rejected edits

The first reason isn't applicable.  I was doing reviews.

The second reason isn't applicable.  It is happening for all questions/answers.

The third reason isn't applicable.  This is on StackOverflow.  Pretty established, plenty of moderators.

The fourth reason shouldn't be applicable.  I'm pretty sure every last one of my edits was approved, based on my reputation increases, though I didn't keep track.  If this is the reason, the threshold has to be **really** low--no more than 10% of my revisions could have been bad edits.  (Is there any way I can check this to be sure?)

So, what could be the cause of this?

Comment: On second thought, I have 59 revisions in the past 9 days.  How many revisions does it take to get banned?  I could have made quite a few bad ones starting out, and tipped it over the edge more recently.

Comment: You seem to do a lot of edits to other peoples posts where you are changing the meaning or trying to "add" to it. Generally, this is not a valid edit. If someone's answer is wrong or incomplete, post your own answer or leave a comment. There are some valid reasons to add extra info, but many of your edits do not count.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks, that's really good advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Revisions** are edits on your own questions, or edits that don't require approval once you have the required reputation. The relevant numbers are your **suggested edits**.

*Almost half* of your suggested edits on Stack Overflow were rejected. Check [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188377/zenexer?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) for a list of suggested edits. You can click the *suggested edit* links on each item to review the result.

All 19 were suggested in the past three days, 10 were approved, 9 were rejected (almost half). Something like this might trigger the ban.

Comment: Really?  Wow, I'm bad at estimating, then.