# Why are some questions not editable

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing edit link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)

Sometime ,I want to edit a question, but the "edit" button isn't there, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658360/table-view-detail-disclosure-ios).

[image: screenshot]

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple cases in which you can't suggest an edit. The most common is that the question already has a suggested edit, which is what's happening [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/218602). Once that edit gets approved/rejected the edit link will come back. It can also happen if the site has too many pending suggestions, but I don't know that that's ever actually happened

Comment: I hope you won't mind me coming over here to say this: your 9/11 analogy to Evan Carroll was amazing.  Wow.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually because there is already an edit pending review on the question.  See [this answer](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/90/69) on meta.biology endorsed by Balpha

Answer (score 1):

That normally happens because there is already a pending edit that needs to be first approved; as you don't have the privilege of approving suggested edits, you don't see the link.

Users who can edit any post, and approve suggested edits see something similar to what shown in this screenshot (taken for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652074/225647)).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

All answers were talking about pending suggested edits, which is the reason in this case, but reason also might be that you're banned because too many of your suggested edits has been rejected.

This is not the case though.