# Our edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits

How many post edits can I do in a day? I think I have submitted less than 10 post edits today, but I am getting the following message:

> Our edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes

[image: The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!]

What does this mean, and when can I start suggesting edits again? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: [What's the fixed size of the suggested edit queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue) features the most up-to-date size of the edit queue.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with you, but rather because suggested edits goes into a queue (20 edits maximum I believe) waiting for others to approve them. Once this queue is full, probably because there aren't enough 10k'ers up right now, you can't make any more suggested edits.

**Edit:** Jeff [increased this limit to 160](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98672/dont-let-people-who-are-suggesting-edits-run-into-a-dead-end-street/98882#98882) on SO, so the chances of this error occurring is fairly low now

Comment: Any 2k+ member can approve as far as I know, and isn't it clearing the queue as well?

Comment: yup that's right, just wanted to clarify that not only 10k'ers can approve/reject suggested edits. :)

Comment: I've run into this issue a couple times over the past few days now. Maybe the limit needs to be increased again?

Comment: I've [strangely] run into this issue now.   Any idea on when/how this limit is maintained?

Comment: Cant fix a post that doesnt work cause of this.

Comment: The error still occurs, which is undoubtedly not very pleasant. More and more changes appear, but few people can check them.

Comment: Same issue at the moment, rip. I just wanted to update a dead link, for anyone going to it later

Comment: I've seen this error twice at SO in the past weeks. Probably 160 is not enough quota anymore.

Comment: This is still an issue at SO.

Comment: It's been happening nearly every time I try to submit an edit lately.

Comment: I must admit I am not sure I want to edit anymore: you spend time editing and then you get the dreaded "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!"... :(

Comment: I get this message. Is it possible to cleanup the edit queue?

Comment: **The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes**! -- I stopped editing a log time ago on stackoverflow.com because of that. Someone really needs to look into this!

Comment: 2022 and still happening all the time... :(

Comment: This is so annoying...

Comment: @yi-jiang, how is this the policy? Why do you allow us to open an edit if we can't finish it? The smart approach is to skip questions that need to edit from the queue.

Comment: It looks like all 2k+ members started doing something else and are really no longer interested in approving edits. I stopped editing it is useless. It is quite a quality hit on SO. I suggest all members start loosing credit points after some time of inactivity

Comment: Do not ask people to review posts that have alredy more than three edits in a queue and change that "error message" into something more descriptive, like: "Thanks for your effort, but we don't need it anymore".

Comment: Even in 2022 still i'm facing the issue

Comment: I wonder how many edit attempts have been abandoned because of this issue

Comment: There should be a warning it is anoying to use a long time to edit a post, for it to be rejected because the queue is full.

Comment: Balancing the number of edits and active reviewers by roughly rejecting new edits is purely self-deceiving. Can't they save pending edits on the server and automatically add them to the queue when available? It's really frustrating to have to abandon an edit just because the queue is accidentally full after spending lots of time on it. But I guess this policy is pretty successful in balancing the "excessive" enthusiasm of the community.

Comment: I can edit or do any of my daily review because of this error

Comment: 2023 I'm facing the issue on SO, maybe the limit should be lifted again?

Comment: in Nove 2023, made my 2nd question edit of the year, and i am still getting the same error, why though?Kind request to time to buff the limit probably?

Comment: 2024 and still happening all the time... :( @gru 
Can it be moved to a proper system queue without limits? 
Asking questions about StackOverflow on StackOverflow ruins the world