# When does the edit privilege come back?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a penalty for one's edit suggestion being rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected)

I lost the edit privilege almost a week ago. All my edit suggestions were taken, but I guess someone found that there were too many. That's fine, I might edit less next time. But I read that the privilege is lost for one day. When will this privilege be granted back to me?

Comment: "But I read that the privilege is lost for one day."

Comment: @zcoop the question was asked about SO but can apply to the whole network. MSE surely existed before this q was asked.

Answer (score 4):

> All my edit suggestions were taken, but I guess someone found that there were too many.

No, they weren't *all* accepted. Your profile [displays a list of all your suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457500/mathieu?tab=activity), and clicking on those links will tell you the status of each. Here's a list of those you've had rejected recently:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/226455
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/226453
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/225403
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/225369
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/225304
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/225125
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/223732
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/177085

I'm not sure if this is enough to trip the automatic temporary ban on suggesting edits, but it might have been. The goal is to encourage you to reflect on why the edits you've made so far have been rejected, and hopefully improve your editing style for the future. The point of the suggested edit system is to "train" new users in how to properly edit. As such, it's worth checking out the rejection reasons even if there *haven't* been enough of your edits rejected to trip the auto-block. And if there *has* been, then you've already answered your own question:

> I read that the privilege is lost for one day.

The other situation in which you would be unable to suggest edits is when the suggested edit queue is full. But since [its maximum size was increased to 160](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98672/dont-let-people-who-are-suggesting-edits-run-into-a-dead-end-street/98882#98882), this shouldn't be a problem. Right now, there are only 50 edits in the queue. And if this were the case, you'd see the message:

> Our edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes

Comment: Is the suggested edit ban really for just one day?  Do you have a reference?  Should I update http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work?

Comment: @Robert: Hmm, no. I wasn't actually suggesting that. I just assumed that the other 6 days have already elapsed.

Comment: Other six days?  Is it seven?  Do you have a reference?

Comment: Hm... I guess I might be considered too picky. I had my questions edited all the time to remove the "How to", but looks like not everyone thinks the same way. I'll edit more carefully next time...

Comment: @Robert: Jeff said [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/78192#78192) that it was 7 days. I'm not sure if that's changed... But the question you linked to actually links to that same answer from Jeff. I suspect there are two separate thresholds, one for education and the other for outright abuse.

Comment: One other situation where a user is unable to suggest edits is when they are looking at a question which has a pending suggested edit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey On _Ask Different_ I have been banned from suggesting further edits, when I had too much rejected edits; the message I got when I tried to suggest a new edit said I should try again in 7 days.