# Lost edit privilege today without having any rejected edit

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a penalty for one's edit suggestion being rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected)
>   [Missing edit link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)
>   [When does the edit privilege come back on Stack overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127492/when-does-the-edit-privilege-come-back-on-stack-overflow)

I just realized that I lost my edit privilege today. The question is why? I've suggested 3 edits in april and all 3 were approved. Anyone knows what could go wrong?

Any clarification is most welcome!

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127492/when-does-the-edit-privilege-come-back-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Never mind, I see what you mean now.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misread.

Comment: Hmm, it _could_ be because the suggested edit queue is full (currently 159) and have nothing to do with you.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the case, I think it should be clearly stated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be related to the current state of the suggested edit queue, and not you. The queue may just be full.