# Bogus message when trying to save a tag wiki edit

Tags: bug, edits, tag-wiki

I have created a new tag on Stack Overflow and I'm trying to edit the wiki for it. I do  not have enough reputation so I get this message on the top of the page.

> You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.

That is OK, but the problem is that when I try to save the edit I get the following error:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>   The tag wiki edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes

This is not a question, this is a tag wiki edit and so I believe this message is incorrect.

Comment: Hrm, did you mistype the error message? It already says that the tag wiki edit queue is full...

Comment: @TheEstablishment - no this is the error message copy-pasted. It is possible that it has already been changed but as of the time of my post I am absolutely sure this has been the error message.

Comment: That's what I don't understand then. You said you were trying to save a tag wiki edit, and the error message was about a tag wiki edit. They match.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - no my post has been edited. The error message read "Your question could not be saved, because the edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes" I have no idea why someone changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see anywhere that tag wikis have their own suggested edit queue thus I assume they are part of the general queue which is [limited to 160 suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98882/152859).

The queue now stands on 158 so what happened make sense.

Anyway the message need to be changed indeed, e.g.

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because: The edit queue is full, try again in a few minutes

Comment: exactly- that is what I thought.