# Tag-wiki edit submit gets error, clearer reasons requested

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, tag-wiki

I'm trying to submit a tag-wiki on Cogsi.SE, whose edit review queue is currently at 38, I keep getting the error:
`An error occurred while submitting the post`

Here's a screenshot of what's happening:
[image: Tag_bug]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

It appears the edit review queue was full. Could this warning be improved please?

Comment: Weird, I don't see any edit link although it says "All registered users may propose new tag wikis". Maybe there's already a suggested edit on it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard In that case, is there already a question for better tag wiki error messages?

Comment: Normally you shouldn't get to that screen as there's no edit link to begin with... you see such link now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, I can click `help us edit this wiki` when I hover over the tag.

Comment: hmm... dunno then. Let's wait for a dev to come over and take a look. :)

Comment: The queue is currently clogged on CogSci.  It should have been dealt with early on, but it escaped everyone's notice.  I think your issue may be related to the overstuffed queue.

Comment: @jonsca I first tried at 40 edits, then again at 38. Does that mean that the edit queue is different for tag-wiki edits and normal edits? Or do I just not understand how the review queue works?

Comment: Well, it worked now that the queue is at 32. I'll change the tags accordingly.

Comment: @Seanny123 It's definitely all the same queue.  It's possible that it was already edited by the other user, or that they were editing 2 more posts when you proposed it.

Comment: I have asked the other user to hang back for a bit, since their proposed edits are going to continue to be in the queue until 2 users approve/reject them.  If you wouldn't mind hanging back for just a bit as well to let some of them get resolved (even though yours are quite helpful and welcome!), that would be of great help.

Comment: Well, it used to show correct message before based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129722/bogus-message-when-trying-to-save-a-tag-wiki-edit?rq=1).

Comment: @Seanny123 I approved your edits, so they should be all set. An aside: I know you work with this framework on a daily basis, but is the "Neurological" a change from "Neural"?  The latter is the only version I see when I google Nengo. I corrected it in the excerpt but not in the main tag wiki.

Comment: @jonsca this tag wiki does not include tag usage guidelines, only the definition. Shouldn't it have been rejected?

Comment: @JanDvorak My personal style is to do it as you describe, but a lot of people seem to do it the OP's way on the science sites, so I don't know if there is any consensus.  I'm less worried if there's something coherent there rather than a blank wiki, as long as it's not plagiarized and makes sense for the questions.  The OP is our resident expert in this framework, so I have respected his judgement.  Feel free to suggest an addendum to the wiki if you think it's incomplete.

Comment: @jonsca Oh my jebus, I work in the lab and I've been mis-naming the framework for three months. I've also improved the tag based off the tag guidelines, as a result of Jan's delightful constructive criticism.