# Why is SO letting me enter edit mode if the edit queue is full?

Tags: discussion, bug, review, edits, suggested-edits

> This is happening quite frequently and this is so annoying

While I'm reviewing **First Posts**, I see some posts that require better formatting and corrections. So, I press the edit button to enter the edit mode.

Sometimes it will not let me edit because of the number of edit suggestions, but sometimes it lets me in and I start making improvements such as correcting spelling, fixing grammar, and improving formatting. If the post is of low quality it takes quite a normal amount of time and effort to edit it. In the end, when I press the **Save edits** button, it "scolds" me saying `The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes`:

[image: 'edit queue is full' message]

This is so **annoying** when you devoted your time to editing and cannot submit it. In other words, you have just wasted your time. Congratulations!

The only option is to wait some time and try again, which usually not works. It just keeps saying "try again", and you have no option to cancel your edits.

---

**Here is the question:**

Why did the system not say it before letting me in to edit mode if the queue is full? I know that someone is submitting an edit suggestion before me, so the queue is filling up when I try to submit my edit. But this is bad and should be fixed!

I think the system should work like this: when someone enters edit mode, it counts it and puts them in the edit queue, and will not let others enter if the queue is full.

Is this a bug in the system? Or is it done deliberately?

> Of course, I read other posts related to this topic, but my question is different and mostly it is a request that this issue be fixed

Comment: I see your point but such attitude isn't a good way to request a change. Also, consider a case when the queue wasn't full when you started the edit, but gets full while you're editing. There's no way the system can predict the future.

Comment: We can't know if in the 30 minutes you spend on the edit the queue will have a slot free.

Comment: If this is mostly a request for the issue to be fixed, it's a dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347615/369802

Comment: I disagree with @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard the system should limit the number of people allowed to start editing, not limit who can submit.
You can reduce frustration just by stopping people from being allowed to start editing when the queue is 90% full. This means the queue will be much less likely to fill up, since for this to happen there must be lots of people already editing and submitting. It's very bad to allow people to start work and then tell them they shouldn't have started because a queue is full. Disregard for community.