# Why is my Edit privilege disabled?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

While trying to edit some posts at Stack Overflow, not all of my suggested edits were approved. After a while, my edit privilege is gone.

Is that because I have a large number of rejected edits?

Comment: A convenient place to say: Please stop editing in *italics* and **bold words** to questions. You're not improving anything, you're just visually cluttering the posts you're editing. On the off chance that your edit is approved, it'll probably just be reverted by somebody else.

Comment: Please also review the [markdown faq](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), you should never have to manually edit insert `<br>` tags, or most any real html tag for that matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if significant amount of your suggested edits have been rejected, you won't be able to suggest edits for a while.

It is also possible that the [suggested edit queue is full](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue), thereby suppressing the edit link.

Comment: And how long is that "while" ?

Comment: I believe it's a week - trying to find this. @Cody