# Increase the default edit queue size (currently it is only 40)

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

It's annoying to have the error message

> The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!

when trying to save some edit. Could the default edit queue be increased?

As [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348447/178179), the default edit queue size is only 40 except for 2 SE websites.

[image]

Comment: Voting this as site-specific. Different sites have different thresholds for suggested edits, and the size of the queue on one specific site should be a decision made for that site.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog I'd suggest to increase the default queue size, which is the most commonly used queue size (according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84398/178179), only 2 SE websites don't use the default queue size).

Comment: So then edit the post to say that. To bolster your request, provide data that shows it's too small a size for many different sites.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog done. I can't provide systematic data, just anecdotes, since I don't have access to many Stack Exchange statistics.

Comment: Could the other close voters explain? The question isn't specific to a single SE website but instead applies to most of them.

Comment: Removed my close vote. By the way, this [had a Leave Open outcome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/72270) an hour ago.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Thanks, interesting, I forgot about these Leave Open votes. Somehow it feels they should be deducted from the close vote count. Looks like that could be my next downvoted feature request :-) though it's probably been proposed in the past.

Comment: I'd support a more elegant solution, maybe have suggested edits expire at some point. But increasing the queue size blindly won't solve the actual problem, just cause even bigger problem(s), as the answer already explains.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance refusing to save edits sounds like a bigger problem to me than having a large backlog, as making an edit can be time consuming and it might fix some critical issues in a post. Does stack overflow have a lower quality of reviews because the queue is 500 instead of 40?

Comment: SO is a totally different level. The quality is lower there anyway, so it's less relevant.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance but did increasing the stack overflow edit queue size led to a lower quality of reviews?

Answer (score 14):

It's annoying, I know (I can't even properly review First Posts on Web Applications right now), but increasing the limit will only cause a larger backlog, less enthusiastic/attentive reviewers and hence worse reviews. Based of what I've seen I'm sure *your* edits are correct, but there are a lot of suggested edits across the network which do need proper scrutiny. Therefore, the number is quite low ([40 on most sites, with a couple exceptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84398/295232)).

Since you're having this problem too, I've posted a plea for help on Web Applications Meta: [Please help reviewing suggested edits!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4733/136642) </shameless plug>

---

I now realize that you do have enough reputation on Web Applications to review regular suggested edits, but was annoyed because you needed empty review slots for suggesting edits to tag wikis/excerpts. In that case, the solution to your problem is ... so obvious I'm not even going to mention it.