# Why did the suggested edit review queue disappear?

Tags: support, review

[image]
As shown, I have 2463 rep in MSE, but suddenly the suggested edit review queue disappeared. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have made [the maximum of 20 suggested edit reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147981/295232) today, see the [statistics page](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats):

[image]

That means you can't review any more items until tomorrow, and therefore the queue is not shown in the menu.

Comment: With such a small number of edit reviews allowed per day, no wonder why the [edit queue sometimes get full and don't accept new edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348445/178179) :-/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt When any review queue gets bigger than a certain value (queue- and site-specific, IIRC), then reviewers are given an extra block of 20, so they can review up to 40/day for those queues that need extra work.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks, even 40 (like on SO) doesn't strike me as very large. In fact for users with enough good reviews, I don't see any point in having a human reachable limit.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It's a topic of much discussion and debate (especially on S.O.). The 'Powers-that-Be' apparently think that more than 40 reviews per queue would be too stressful/tiring for mere humans - but not (obviously) for moderators.

Comment: @AdrianMole I trust mere humans to stop reviewing whenever they want.