# Can't suggest an edit for specific question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021088/augmented-reality), and it has horrid spelling/grammar/formatting that I'd like to correct. Usually I find an Edit link under a question so I can suggest a revision to it. In this case, it's missing, as pictured here:

[image: no edit link]

Why can't I suggest an edit for this question?

Comment: Oh you wanted "Argument Reality"?  That's down the hall.

Comment: You may be interested in [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions), if you find the "hiding of the edit link" behavior confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was already a suggested edit for the question. Now that it has been approved, the edit link should reappear.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware that causes the link to disappear. I just checked the question again, and it looks a lot nicer and the edit link is now there. Thanks!