# Was there was a recent change to the privileges?

Tags: support, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)

Was there a privilege change in the last hour? I am no longer able to edit questions and answers.

I checked the privileges list and it appears I now only have 84% of the required reputation.

Comment: The suggested edit review queue is full at the moment. Had you ever above 2K rep? If not, it's just the fullness of the edit queue.

Comment: @Lucifer: Yep...

Comment: @DanielFischer I was not above 2k I am just shy of 1700. So I quess it is a queue size issue.

Comment: Since this is happening more often, perhaps it wouldn't hurt to throw up a slightly different error message? *"The stack is currently overflowing...please wait a bit and try to submit your edit again."*

Comment: and add it to the FAQ

Comment: @TheEstablishment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions