# Why can't I edit this question?

Tags: support, edits, specific-question

I just saw [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139757/should-books-tag-is-necessary-on-so) and thought it needed further editing (starting with the title). I wanted to edit it, but the edit link was disabled. Why?

Comment: [Possibly related change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138944/130268). *"When a registered user (< 2k rep) cannot suggest an edit we will gray out the edit link instead of removing it. The tooltip text will explain why an edit cannot be suggested."*

Comment: I edited it, then realized how bad the title was and suggested another that hasn't been reviewed yet

Comment: Thank you Michael. I'm on an iPad right now, so I couldn't see the tooltip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a pending edit for that post.

Comment: Makes sense. So I don't see the indicator because I don't have edit privileges on Meta. I got so used to them on SO, that I didn't even think of that.

Comment: The edit has been approved now.

Comment: May add reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138944/186879