# Why is the edit link grayed out and retag link missing?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits, edits

I was going to retag a question but it didn't have the link. Also the edit link was grayed out. It is 31 minutes old and I have they are there on other questions. What situations does this happen in?

Comment: It probably had a pending suggested edit.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: Other situations: full suggested edit queue, temporary edit ban because of too many rejected edits.

Comment: It came back now but it was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567632/extracting-specific-data-from-a-web-page-using-php/11567973#11567973 maybe because jumpnett was editing it, though it shouldn't have taken more than a few seconds to add the one tag he did :S

Comment: @Celeritas That had to be approved, that took a couple of minutes. http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/322861

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hover over it. [The link will tell you.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138944/150909)

It's in the hovertext. `:)` As mentioned in the comments, it can happen for many reasons, most likely the edit queue is full. The link used to be removed completely, but a recent feature change leaves it on the page, greyed out.