# Make the error "This edit would have to be a suggested edit" more verbose

Tags: feature-request, feedback

From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190687/this-edit-would-have-to-be-a-suggested-edit-edit-button-grayed-out) post I found that the error `"This edit would have to be a suggested edit"` occurs because there has already been an edit suggested for the same post, but the error message is still confusing. Can the error `"This edit would have to be a suggested edit"` be made more verbose?