# Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, rejected-edits, edit-ban

First time I've got the following message on SO:

> Too many of your edits were rejected,
>   try again in 7 days.

Although, I have made **~50 accepted edits** this day.

I'm sure that should outweigh the **~5 rejected edits**, right?

---

**My suggestion:**

```
bool allowEdit(USER u)
{
    if(u.rejected * 5 > u.accepted)
        return(false);
    else
        return(true);
}
```

Think of it this way: if I do a 1000 accepted edits, and mess up on 5 [rejected], does that mean I should get banned for 7 days?

---

Hmmm... There seems to be a bug; the message only appears when clicking edit from review.

But otherwise, I can't edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5665696/365102), even when going to it from the homepage.

Comment: So in other words, whether you can suggest edits should depend on the ratio of rejected to accepted (or total), rather than some fixed number.

Comment: @JeffM Exactly.

Comment: Or `return (u.AcceptedEdits > u.RejectedEdits * 5);` That way you don't have that nasty `return true` or `return false` for a boolean function.

Comment: @George This is more other-languages friendly, although, I must admit, that option hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: @muntoo languages that don't treat boolean conditions as a first class type make me cry. Which languages are you referring to?

Comment: @George No idea, but I meant it to be "pseudocode" (in a way).

Comment: (Also, 7 days is a long time to learn some small point that I didn't quite gather!)

Comment: Where can I view the reasons my edits were rejected?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I just amended it to take into account your accepts.

When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last **7 days** of activity.

If `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5`, you will be auto-banned.

Note that "rejects" is the count of rejections made by human users/moderators only, rejections made by the Community bot as a result of a conflict [are ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/152859).

Comment: is this with order of operations

Comment: @AnishGupta `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) > 5`. In other words, rejects are three times as sensitive as approvals.

Comment: Looking at the last X days of activity has a simple problem: I have 1000 accepted edits. I go on vacation for a week, then when I return, some [uninformed mods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149631/how-can-i-notify-moderators-of-incorrect-edit-rejections) reject [my 5 edits from the past hour](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Now I'm banned. **Please instead look at the last X edits.**

Comment: Agree immensely with Dan Dascalescu.  Seem's like it this should be weighted more based on a longer trend of activity. Granted I'm a noob on editing clearly (and an offender) but a week long ban is quite a nuisance when you never get a chance to stop and say oops better be careful I'm on thin ice, I'll stop and wait a minute.

Comment: @DanDascalescu If it looks only at the last X edits, then there is no way for the block to ever expire.

Comment: Just for clarification here, is an approval vs rejection defined as each reviewer's action of marking approve / reject on a suggestion, or as a suggestion itself being rejected (e.g., from receiving 3 rejects and 1 accept)?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure I'm for this.   While I do appreciate that someone is cleaning up posts that need it (the 50 approved edits), I wonder at the quality of those edits if > 5 were rejected.

I like that once you hit a decent number of rejects, the system says "hey, slow down".  I *don't* like the idea that once a user spams a huge number of correct spelling changes they could also spam a bunch of poor edits as well.

Comment: Everyone with enough edits gets some rejected.  It's like [the interview anti-loop](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-that-job-at-google.html)

Comment: @Renesis It's okay to have a bad edit every now and then, but if you cluster up a whole bunch of bad edits at once, that's rather annoying to deal with, I would imagine. It's something of a good reason for a single user to not queue up several dozen edits at once.

Comment: @GraceNote Then perhaps a rate limiter should be put in place before they send all of those edits?