# Reputation tab: Are these really votes?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem in multiple edits listing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101845/problem-in-multiple-edits-listing)

[image]

Look closely at the FHC. How does `1 edit + 1 accepted == 2 votes`?

Comment: @Cody That was from SO, not meta.SO.

Comment: @Cody No, I meant that you can only get banned from one site. On other SE sites, you can still edit. This includes meta. EDIT: The "*[Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91392/152657)*" is a question.

Comment: So you're just saying that instead of "votes", the word should be something more neutral, like "events'?

Comment: @Cody Yes, "events" or something else that fits the context.