# Problem in multiple edits listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, edits

On Stack Overflow, when I look at my reputation explanation I see that I've got two votes and gotten +4, but when I look inside I see that there are actually two edits there. Isn't this a mistake when listing multiple edits?

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: See [Reputation tab: Are these really votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92342) (since the bounty is close-vote-blocking me)

Comment: My question is in Stackoverflow....

Comment: @nayish: It's the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we'll no longer roll up suggested edit approvals in the "votes", they'll appear as their own line.

Also, there was a bug with missing titles/links on +2 on accepted answers (since the vote goes with the *answer* behind the scenes)...this is also corrected in the next build.