# It says "2 votes" instead of "2 edits"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

There is a line in my reputation list saying the following:

```
+4   1 min ago  2 votes  C++ code compiles in CentOS g++, but not in Visual studio 2008
```

It is weird, because 2 votes should be +20, not +4. So, I expand it, and I see this, which is correct:

```
+2   14:54  edit     
+2   14:46  edit
```

So, it is not 2 votes, it is 2 edits. (Which I would not mind if they were combined into 1 edit.)

Screenshot of issue:

[image]

Comment: Looks like typo indeed, note that when you group by time (not by post) it shows the correct "*+4  9 mins ago edit C++ code compiles in CentOS g++, but not in Visual studio 2008*"

Comment: Hmm, seems like this might be an unaccounted-for case of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101845/150235)

Comment: Corresponding revision list: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8669217/revisions. Three revisions by the OP: 14:43:46 (retag), 14:46:11 (retag) and 14:54:55 (edit, title only).

Comment: yep, we are going to fix this after a big refactor that Nick and Geoff are working on ...

Answer (score 2):

In the rollup we now say "2 events" instead of "2 votes", this will roll out to other sites as [the rest of the rep changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) do.