# Tag editing limits - Give us a chance

Tags: feature-request, support, tag-wiki, rate-limiting

As per [Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days), there is a limit on editing tags.

Over on the [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) SE, I made 26 accepted edits, and 9 rejected ones. (Sorry if I've counted wrong, it's really hard to tell)

I am now blocked for 7 days! What on earth! I made 9 edits that were in good faith (okay, that sounds like a lot, but I was never told how to improve, I didn't even know they were not being accepted), just not quite right, and I am now blocked for 7 days!

I wasn't notified when my suggestions were not accepted and given a reason to improve there and then. I have only now found out how you see the reason that was given, tucked away in some corner of the profile.

See my Q [here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days-what-did-i-do-wrong#comment197_161).

We have a saying "don't bite the newcomers (especially if they are doing it in good faith)" on Wikipedia, and I have been bitten pretty hard really.

**Having been told how to improve, don't I deserve a second chance?**

By the time I am allowed to edit again, the site will have changed a lot.

When a site is in an early beta, if you can't think of anything to ask or answer, editing is the only way to earn reputation (I know everybody says "reputation doesn't matter", but get real, when you don't have much it matters a hell of a lot).

I'm not trying to sound as though I'm sulking, but **my desire to help out has been severely lowered.**

To be honest, I am appalled (sorry, but it's the truth).

I'm sorry if I seem angry (I am...), but 7 days is an impossibly long time for a site that has only been open for 8.

**So please can something be done before other users like me leave the site because of this?**

Comment: *"By the time I am allowed to edit again, the site will have changed dramatically."*.. in 7 days...really? Relative to the site's existence that might seem long, but in reality there will most likely not be a huge change. You'll get your second chance in a couple of days.

Comment: @Bart What do you mean couple of days? It says 7.

Comment: Yeah, I meant "a few days"..7 indeed.

Comment: Besides, you can still edit  your own post, right? Editing isn't that important, someone else can do it. Or is it a complete ban (not just an edit ban)

Comment: @Manish (Edit ban) When a site is in an early beta, if you can't think of anything to ask or answer, editing is the only way to earn reputation (I know everybody says "reputation doesn't matter", but get real, when you don't have much it matters a hell of a lot).

Comment: @acart private beta privilege levels are lower, so rep really is easier to get. Rack your brains and try to remember all your previous questions about the topic (I did that for chem.SE). You probably made some not-so-good edits in your hurry to get rep. Ask questions, you'll get rep muuuch faster..

Comment: I don't really see how this question can be answered constructively. Perhaps you can restate it to discuss the visibility of rejected suggested edits under the assumption that, should you have seen the rejections, you would have changed your actions sooner. That would be something to discuss (although there might be a dupe?). With respect to the other issues: you'll get your second chance in 7 days. The temporary inability to earn reputation through edits is not a big concern. And I don't foresee a mass exodus of users because of issues similar to yours.

Comment: If you can't ask or answer anything then you shouldn't have committed to the beta.

Comment: See [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624) — I think the proper thing to do in this case would have been to provide you discoverable feedback, which is unfortunately not done currently.

Comment: Agree with ACarter disagree with Bart.  Sorry if I had seen i was CLOSE to the limit i would have stopped and asked first rather than hitting the limit.  This seems to be the exact opposite of what is preached to be told to first time contributors. Bart might not forsee it, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything (no disrespect intended).