# Changing the edit limit for tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, rate-limiting

Following on from [my previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136915/tag-editing-limits-give-us-a-chance#comment382873_136915) (which I admit was not very well thought out), I have decided to ask a better question.

When too many of your tag wiki suggestions get rejected, you get banned for 7 days, which I think is harsh if you are editing in good faith, and just are not quite sure what you are doing.

I have two ideas:

#### IDEA 1

The current check is `if (rejects - approvals / 3) > 5`, and it will block you for 7 days.

What I propose is a gentler introduction. When you get close to that limit you get blocked for 2 days to be warned, and only get blocked for 7 if you're level continues to deteriorate.

`if (rejects - approvals / 3) > 3`, block for 2 days.

then, `if (rejects - approvals / 3) > 5`, block for 7 days

#### IDEA 2

At least give us a warning if we are going to get blocked!

When the `(rejects - approvals / 3)` level is getting closer to 5 (say, on 4), give a warning that something might happen.

A proper warning, something like:

> Your edit rejection level is getting too high and you are close to being blocked. Have a look at your suggestion history [here] and the tag-wiki guidelines [here]

Mainly **I think the current system just blocks the user, without warning them or anything.** When I got blocked, I didn't even know where to find the suggestion history to see what I had done wrong, so now I have 7 days being banned from tag-wiki editing. Not good, seeing as I *was* so eager to help out.

If I had been given either of the two options above instead of a straight ban, I would not be blocked now, but would know what I did wrong, and as a result, that SE site would be better off with the edits I would have done.

Comment: While I agree in principle with idea 1, it is very complex for what is actually a rare case. On the other hand idea 2 is spot on, a 7-day ban shouldn't fall down out of nowhere.

Answer (score 6):

See [this answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/155826), which addresses the problems of having a lack of useful feedback to users whose suggested edits on questions and answers are rejected by the community, and which provides some possible solutions to providing this feedback to users who suggest these edits.

The main idea of this answer is that the rejection notice should appear to the user before they make the mistake again. For tag wiki edits, this could be displayed as a banner above the tag wiki edit screen (but not as a notification, which we've established is reserved for "You rock!" type messages):

> WARNING: Your last 2 tag wiki edits were rejected. Click here to learn why.

The same feature request for suggested edits on posts should apply equally to suggested edits on tag wikis. Feedback is important in coaching people and providing them with the necessary guidance to change or improve a specific set of behaviors, even if those actions are currently conducted in good faith.

In cases where a user could be suspended for too many rejected edits, this feedback is critical.

Comment: Thanks for that ([I also answered that question as it happens!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137333/179735)) The idea of having it above the edit box is a great one! I had not thought of it, but it is probably the best solution really.