# Non logged in users can edit questions, but logged in users can't?

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)

When logged out on the Raspberry Pi site, and looking at a question, I can edit it (well suggest an edit)

[image when not logged in http://adams-site.x10.mx/v/not-logged-in.png](http://adams-site.x10.mx/v/not-logged-in.png)

However, when logged in, I can't even suggest an edit.

[image when logged in http://adams-site.x10.mx/v/logged-in.png](http://adams-site.x10.mx/v/logged-in.png)

Why on earth is this? Surely someone with 277 Rep should at least be able to suggest an edit if someone logged out can?

So can this not be changed? Either so none of them can suggest an edit, or so both of them can ? (Personally I think the second, but it's the consistency that counts.)

Comment: Maybe [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions/81701#81701) applies to your [logged in account](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/186/acarter?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)?

Comment: Have you had any previous edits rejected?

Comment: @Chris Not on questions but tag wikis, yes. ([changing the edit limit for tag wikis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136934/changing-the-edit-limit-for-tag-wikis#))

Comment: Hmm - I wonder if rejected tag wiki edits count against you for post edits as well?

Comment: @ChrisF as far as I can see tag wiki edit suggestions are still edit suggestions so most likely the answer is yes - this both make sense and explain what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say this is because there is a suggested edit pending, but it looks like you had a good number of suggested edits rejected on Jun 18 (7 of 15). That could have caused a (7-day, I believe) edit ban. I believe the current condition is `rejected - (accepted/3) > 5`. That would be 4 1/3 currently, not enough to trigger it at the moment, but perhaps at some point that day your ratio *did* trip the ban and it wasn't reversed when you got back below the threshold.

Comment: Any reference for that formula? (Jeff referred to ["absolute value"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions/81701#81701) a year ago.)

Comment: I just saw it a couple days ago, I'll see if I can track it down.