# How can I find whether my suggested edit was approved or rejected?

Tags: support, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

I checked with [Rejected Statistics](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits) for me, **UserID: 696134**,  it shows only 2 records for rejected. While in picture below it says 24 edits rejected for me (Jennis).

As per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days) formula is:

```
(rejects - approvals / 3) > 5
```

In my case, the values are:

```
(24 - 77/3) > 5 becomes false
```

I believe I have missed something. What am I missing here?

[image: 24 edits]

Comment: Stack Exchange Data Explorer does not have real time data.

Comment: And downvote for ? Being dumb ?

Comment: Can u help me how can I check which edits were rejected so in future I can be cautious while suggesting edits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/696134/jennis?tab=activity&sort=suggestions - also read that post you linked to, it's calculated over a 7 day sliding window, not your global stats.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences, @Jennis. (Remove the bug tag and you might get less downvotes.)

Comment: @Mat Thax did that. Is there any to find which suggested edits were rejected ? So in future I can be cautious while suggesting edits.

Comment: See the previous link I posted. All your suggested edits are on your profile page.

Comment: Go through each of the [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/696134/jennis?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and see what comments the reviewers have left for you.

Comment: Rejection messages really [need to be more in your face](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) — how on earth are users supposed to find this?

Comment: @Mat I got how to check rejected edit, but as per calculations It is still not correct. Isn't it ? Any thoughts. Please assist.

Comment: Did you take into account the 7 day sliding window?

Comment: @Mat currently as per answer I see suggestions, there it shows 94 suggestions. And As attached screenshot in question 77 approved and 24 rejected so is it updated ? I am still confused about 7 day sliding window.

Comment: Take into account only the last 7 days (from this time last week to now) for the suggested edit suspension. Suggested edits before this time last week are not considered.

Comment: @mat Thax got it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Using Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)

Stack Exchange data explorer does not have real time data. As per its [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq), the data is updated monthly. You cannot compute your suggested edits statistics based on SEDE data.

#### Steps to find the status of suggested edits

Here is one way to find out whether a suggested edit was approved or rejected. Sure, this is not the most efficient way.

1. Go to your user profile on Stack Overflow
2. Click `Activity` tab
3. Click `Suggestions` within Activity tab
4. Click `suggested edit` link

This action will take you to the suggested edit. It will show whether it was approved or rejected. Since you have only 94 suggested edits, may be you could find out all the rejected ones by going through each one of the suggested edits.

May be someone else has a better way to figure this out.

[image: Suggested edits]

Comment: Thax. Now I Got it.

Comment: SEDE isn't updated monthly, not anymore, it hasn't been updated since June (check its frontpage). There's a plan for weekly updates, but it might take awhile.

Comment: @YannisRizos: In that case, someone should update the SEDE FAQ. :-)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data