# Repercussions when suggested edits are rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Do I, as a user, receive any form of repercussion when getting rejected suggested edits?

1. No
2. Yes, after n number of declined suggested edits, I will not able to suggest edits for a while. ( Timeout )
3. Yes, after n number of declined suggested edits, I will get banned from suggesting edits.
4. Yes, but something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, after you have to much edits rejected, you get banned 7 days from suggesting edits.
Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/229438

> I just amended it to take into account your accepts.
>
> When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last **7 days** of activity.
>
> If `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5`, you will be auto-banned.