# How was this suggested edit rejected with only one vote?

Tags: discussion, bug, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I was just reviewing suggested edits, and I rejected [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3649042).

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this edit was rejected with only one vote? Usually it requires 3 votes unless the author rejects it. This wasn't the case, as I'm not the author.

There haven't been any other edits on the post [since December 5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20393530/revisions).

> [image: Rejected img]

[Perhaps the number of rejects required has been lowered](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1700326#1700326) for editors with a bad accept to reject ratio? Since that isn't very likely, I assume this is a bug.

Comment: `Perhaps the number of rejects required has been lowered for editors with a bad accept to reject ratio?` If only.  Alas, I'm rather confident that's not the case here.

Comment: You didn't by chance happen to have been a mod 2 hours ago and had your superpowers since removed?

Comment: Can the original editor choose to revert during that time?

Comment: @Servy "@JoshC Invisible sneaky mods?" http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1700319#1700319

Comment: It's a Christmas miracle!

Comment: Most of the time when we have things like this, it's because someone went in and edited after the user (and then @Community rejects it).  Doesn't seem to be the case here, but maybe invisibly so?

Comment: Yeah, but there are no other edits on that answer, @Joe (other than one from 12/5).

Comment: We should note that your reject vote was 7 seconds *before* the edit was officially marked as rejected. So your vote didn't directly cause the rejection, but something certainly happened to cause it.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Hence, 'invisibly so'.  :)

Comment: @animuson How long until this is visible on Data explorer and non-staff can investigate? :)

Comment: (answers own question) It's updated every Monday morning, so sadly we need to wait a week to find out... and I'm guessing 12/30 isn't a day a lot of us are going to be thinking about that ;)  (Or, are we?)

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if suggested edits on old, accepted answers requires unanimous approval by reviewers.

Comment: Could this come from a moderator right/privileges? They can already close question without voting.

Comment: @user2284570 no, the moderator would be listed in such case.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this guy attempted to edit the same post [**6 times**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3034861/phoenix?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) (gotta appreciate the dedication..), I'm only guessing here but this might have triggered some auto tool that retracted his edit privileges. This would also explain animusons' comment about the timing.

Edit: I see that the last reject was by the author himself, maybe that prevents further edits? 
If anyone (without instant edit privileges) is interested - try to edit this answer and i'll reject, then try again :)

Comment: Nope, according to [the formula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337), `(5 - (1 /3)) = 5 - 0.33 = 4.67` so he's not yet banned. +1 for spotting this though! EDIT: disregard formula, the first 5 suggestions are older than a week so don't count.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, thanks for the link! Could there be some extra weight to rejects by the author of the post?

Comment: @Leeor don't think so, it's just a binding vote. Checking other lead now...

Comment: Dead end... found more of this kind using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/156014/list-of-posts-with-edits-from-same-user-rejected-in-a-row) (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2250116/user2250116?tab=activity) but none show this weird reject behaviour.