# When will I be able to review again?

Tags: discussion, review

I was trying to review [first-post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) in SO, but it showed me error, `Too many of your edits were rejected.` I get it, that I've made a mistake of editing too many 
QAs and some of them got rejected and I'm sorry for that. I want to understand, how long (some approx. time frame) will I see this message? Is it temporary or permanent status?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you figure out why your edits were rejected or how you can improve your editing?

Comment: Yes, I did. I need to read and understand the content deeper and edit it accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is [somewhat related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/245360). It explains that for the *automatic* review ban, you will be blocked for *at most* seven days.

It takes into account accepted edits too, so it is possible that some older suggested edits got rejected, and you were banned. After some time other suggested edits get approved, which will reduce the rejected edits ratio, which will get you out of the ban.

I don't think this happened, but if the ban was done by *a moderator*, the ban period can vary, depending on the times you were banned or the severity of the rejected edits.

Comment: So, can I know how many days are remaining? I don't want exact days, but apprx. days would be fine. Can I know if it was automatic or not? :)

Comment: No. Usually on SE sites: if there isn't a notice on the number of days, they just don't know.

Comment: ok. Anything I can do to get ban revoked sooner?

Comment: No. Remember that next time you edit ;)

Comment: ok.. Will keep that in mind. :)