# How many edit rejections before the 2nd ban?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, edit-ban

I was recently banned from suggesting edits due to too many of my edits being rejected on Arqade. I didn't understand that I couldn't use Wikipedia descriptions for tag descriptions. I've taken the time I've been banned to reconsider my strategy  and understand my mistake. I don't plan on repeating it.

I would like to continue being a productive member of the community by suggesting helpful edits, but I am hesitant. If my next edit is rejected, will I be banned immediately, or will it take a few more rejected edits for me to be banned a second time?

I was banned the first time for getting five edits rejected; will it take another five rejected edits to get banned a second time, or just one? I don't plan on suggesting poor or sub-par edits, but I just want to know if I have some "buffer room," if for any reason my next edit gets rejected.

For future reference, if I am banned *n* times, how many more rejected edits does it take me to get banned *n+1* times?

I know this happened to me on Arqade, but I am asking on general Meta because I am wondering how this works for the SE network as a whole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an automatic system to get you banned from suggested edits. 
Considering the amount of approves and rejects (2 approved edits, 5 rejected), this is most likely what happened. This ban will expire in seven days from the last rejected edit, so on the 16th of August.

This [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days) describes the conditions for a ban, although it is quite old, so it might be outdated. 

This [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1) describes the conditions for getting a warning.

**The first post I linked is outdated.** The condition that has been stated there is `rejected - approved/3 > 5`, but `rejected - approved/3` is only `4 1/3` in your case. The exact details of when you get an edit ban (or any ban) are generally not made known, to avoid that people will just do what they need to keep below the threshold. So I don't suspect that this will be updated.

For a system ban, only the number of approved and rejected edits in the past week will be counted. Since you were banned for a week, those will be zero if you start editing again.

If you make less than three rejected edits, I suspect you won't be banned, but I can't know it for sure. At least you won't be banned if you have just one edit rejected.