# Can not Edit Question

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)

I am successfully able to Edit some questions. But some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801218/how-launch-android-intent-action-call-in-service-class) like , I am not able to edit this question. why so ? In that question there is no link of Edit.

Comment: It had a pending edit.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else (Java again!) has already suggested an edit so it blocked additional suggestions until it's approved or rejected. See this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8801218/revisions).

It was proposed 13 minutes ago and approved 4 minutes ago, so while in the queue people with less than 2K reputation won't see the edit link indeed.

Comment: ohh... Java... again.. if he was not there , then I could have change to earn 2 reputation points.

Comment: Yeah, looks like he's stalking you! ;)

Comment: I must become fast editor & replier...

Comment: @Arjun don't worry you're showing him dust when it comes to edits.! :)

Comment: ok , I can see Edit Link now.  Thanks for help. is that your baby's photo ?

Comment: Lol sorry it's native phrase in my language guess it's not translated directly to English! Anyhow I meant you leave him far behind as you got much more edits and you're more active than him. As for baby yep she's mine. :-)