# No edit button? New questions

Tags: discussion, edits, new-answers

Somewhat curious. Regarding sometimes no edit button on new questions. Is Jeff correct here ** or am I missing something?

I found this duplicate but I am not sure I *really* understand. [questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions).

I have noticed that sometimes I find new questions (1 - 3 minutes old) that has **no edit button**. According to above it seems that. The answer to this could be that **`"3 There is an edit to a particular post that was not approved yet. "`. But then again. I have tried to edit questions where. When I have edited the qw it says something like `your edit could not be accepted because someone else has already edited the qw. Your edit will only be accepted if it is a more substantial edit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's because another user with less than 2000 reputation already hit the *edit* link and suggested an edit.

The "your edit could not be accepted because someone else has already..." message might appear in the following scenario:

1. User **with 2K and above rep** clicks the edit first and starts editing the post.
2. You click the *edit* and start editing.
3. The first user finishes his edit and submits.
4. Voila! You got the above alert.