# Edit link missing on question (even though I have more than 2k rep)

Tags: support, edits, mobile-web

I encountered a weird issue now, for the first time - there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565279/i-have-a-sequence-of-list-with-1-and-0-and-i-would-like-output-in-this-format-wh) for which I didn't see an edit link at first. However when I manually crafted an edit URL with this post ID and submitted a tiny edit to test it, it worked and now I *do* see the edit link.

I checked existing meta questions about missing edit links ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119445/no-edit-button-new-questions), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)) and none of the answers seem to apply here because a) I was logged in, b) I have more than 2k rep (so all the points related to the editing queue should be irrelevant), c) it's not a tag wiki.

This is how it looked initially:

[image: question screenshot]

What happened there?

**EDIT:** I just realized something even stranger happened. My edit now seems to contain someone else's changes (I just added a colon, not reformatted everything!) plus an edit summary that I didn't write!

It would seem as if there was a pending edit and I implicitly did "improve edit" on it but normally in this case the link *is* there and I get a message about the pending edit with options about what to do with it...

[image: edit log screenshot]

Comment: Ooh. OK, that explains it. I didn't realize because I did switch to desktop view to check if it's mobile-only, but I now realize that this was just a desktop-sized version of the mobile site. (which I swear was different in the past, I used to get the full-fledged desktop site when I did that...)