# Maximum number of edits

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)

I can't see the `edit` option under the posts. Did I reach a limit or something? Is there a maximum pending edit request size?

Comment: There is a maximum size on the edit queue, but it's not there at the moment. I think there's a per day limit for editors though too.

Comment: You should check the feedback on your [recent suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1063093/phadaphunk?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), which have been rejected.

Comment: Is there a place specefic for edits ? or is it just in `activity`?

Answer (score 7):

Looking through your edit history quite a few have been rejected for being too minor. A series of rejected edits causes a temporary block on new edits.

Comment: How can I see if I'm temporarly blocked ?

Comment: Looks like Shog threw down the hammer :P

Comment: @pha - You can see who rejected your edits - http://stackoverflow.com/users/1063093/phadaphunk?tab=activity - click on the `suggested edit` link to see a review of the edit and it's status.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - I don't think there's a direct way of answering that (possibly a mod can look), but the edit queue is not full at the moment

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Hope I won't be locked for a long period -_-'

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - the linked question suggests it's a week. For what it's worth adding a more helpful message than "improved formatting" would be worth doing. I normally itemise the changes, justifying the ones that might be misinterpreted and link to the faq on signatures if I remove one.

Comment: a week.. thats overkill but anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that the suggested edit queue is full - there can be a maximum of 200 suggested edits at any one time.

At the time of posting this answer this limit has not yet been reached so that is not the problem in **this case** but that is valid possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you **do not** see the edit button, this could mean that there is a suggested edit pending and you do not have the privileges to approve suggested edits.

Comment: I don't see it on any post.