# Delay in editing questions?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, edit-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-dont-i-see-an-edit-button-under-questions)

I am new to Stack Overflow and curious about the editing process. Since I am new to programming as well and still want to give back to the community instead of simply receiving answers (I'm not the best at answering questions!), I've been trying to help edit posts. So far, almost all of my edits have been accepted.

Today, I witnessed something interesting though... I had edited three questions, and then couldn't edit any other ones! I frantically searched for reasons for an "edit ban" or the like, but I found nothing concrete.

Then I checked 15 minutes later and could edit posts again. Is this delay a way to prevent computers from running boogie edits? Or am I dancing with an edit ban?

Comment: See [Why don't I see an edit button under questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681)

Comment: ah. Thank you, as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were banned from editing for too many rejections, it'd have been for a week. :)

Right now the edit queue on Stack Overflow is hovering near maximum capacity, so it's probably just that the queue was full and then a few edits got approved in the 15 minutes you were away.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the edit ;)