# Edit post not working

Tags: support, stack-overflow, help

When I am going to any questions on Stack Overflow, that time edit button is appearing as disable. I can't click on it because there is no link of editing. Can you please help me what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of several posts that I can't find at the moment. However, you will get the reason if you but HOVER with your mouse over the disabled link.

Comment: Simple search on meta for "edit disabled" could have saved you lots of time. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal. Sometimes the edit link is not enabled because another user who has less than 2K reputation has just suggested an edit on that post. So unless that suggested edit gets reviewed, the edit link is not enabled for other users below 2K reputation.

But if you are getting a disabled edit link on all questions and answers, that means too many of your suggested edits got rejected and you can't suggest edits for the next 7 days.

For other reason please read this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/214722).

Comment: but I am getting this on every questions

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: okay thanks.. I didn't get any notification like ban?

Comment: Nopes, you dont get it, notification ban for such ban.

Comment: ok so how much time it will take?

Comment: @SumitBijvani This also means you should study your rejected suggestions to find out what you may have done wrong, so you don't get banned again. And again.

Comment: Yes, studying will make you not to repeat same mistake again, which will actually helps system to make clean.

Comment: sure @J.Steen I will study, what I have made wrong.

Comment: @SumitBijvani, please see this your [suggestions list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1087998/sumit-bijvani?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: @Raynold okay let me check all the edits