# Do poor editors get flagged if enough of their edits are rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

I have recently reviewed several subsequent edits for the same person placing an "ios" tag on multiple iDevice questions.  I saw at least 5 before I decided to stop reviewing and flagging him at "too minor", and simply ask here.

I suspect he's likely just editing on auto-pilot for the badge.  Do they get flagged as poor editors after some time, or is this legit behavior and should nothing be done about him (and similar)?

Comment: Well if he's really badge hunting, he will be very disappointed since tag-only edits don't count towards the editing badges anyways. But there's also the +2 reputation reward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If enough edits get rejected they could get edit banned for a week.

Source: [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)

Comment: Do those who are edit-banned get reviewed by the moderators, or only in special circumstances?  If it happens more than once, are they flagged for review?