# Checking when my edit suspension will be over

Tags: support, edit-ban

I have been prohibited from making any further edits on Stack Overflow for a week.

How can and where can I check when exactly I'll be able to make edits again?

Comment: I am pretty sure if that if you try to make another edit, it will let you know how many days of "no-no" you have left.

Comment: What tooltip do you get when you hover on *edit* button?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681/212576

Comment: @hjpotter92 - But the question is not *why is it disabled?*. The question is *How many days are remaining?*

Comment: Take a look at your last rejected audit - take the date it was rejected on. Add 7 days.

Comment: @Oded yes i know tat calculation of keeping a track manually, what i wanted to ask was is it also shown anywhere only to me in my profile or somewhere else.

Comment: Normally it should tell you if you hover the "edit" label

Comment: @hugo my edit link is disables, and when i hover it just give the message of account being disabled from editing, it doesnt show the number of days left.

Comment: If you managed to get yourself banned from editing, should you really be editing?

Comment: @Dukeling, i guess you have not read my question too properly, question is where can i or say in wider scope, where can a user see the days remaining for his ban to be lifted from editing and not whether i can edit or not.

Comment: I did read your question properly, I'm just saying, as a general rule, if you get banned for something, you might not be the best person to be doing it (thus how long until you can do it again shouldn't matter). But most bans on StackOverflow are temporary because people can learn from their mistakes, and I'm not one to say what you can and can't do, I'm just asking you to ask yourself whether you truly understand why you got banned and managed to learn from it. As a side note, comments may comment on an aspect of the question, even if not answering the question (they're not answers).

Comment: @Dukeling, @ the very first i agree that some of the edits that i made were not too great and i agree the protocols under which i'm banned, i have no objection for the ban imposed on me because i learned that i need to make some really good edits to gain reputation. The second thing, if i make a certain mistake doesn't me i cant do that thing correct ever again, try try until you succeed. Hence how long until you can do it again should actually matter for me because i want to contribute for more better edit. I guess this should be the end of this argument, with my question still unanswered.