# You can get around the suggested edit pending blocker

Tags: bug, review, edits, suggested-edits

The [post about the edit button being disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) says:

> There is an edit to a particular post that was not approved yet.

This suggests that you *shouldn't* be able to edit a question, however:

> [image]

This question has a suggested edit waiting

> [image]

I can get the post ID (598784)

> [image]

Go to http://sitename.se/posts/postid/edit (e.g. [askubuntu.com/posts/598784/edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/598784/edit) )

> [image]

You can edit the question. This works on answers too.

I'm not sure this should be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. You are *encouraged* to review a suggested edit, but not *made* to. The edits of a 2k users (or the edits of OP) have more priority than the suggested edits and a suggested edit should not block the edit of a user who has editing privileges. You can edit this post and the suggested edit would be rejected by Community as conflicting.

But I wouldn't advice you to do it. At least so as not to waste the effort of the user who suggested the edit. And if you *really* think that the edit makes the post worse, you can do the same thing in a more legal way: choose "reject and edit" when reviewing. If you feel that the suggested edit is good and in the same time you want to apply your changes, review the suggested edit by choosing "improve" and adding something from you.