# Blocked from editing due to pending review

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Currently a pending edit needs two approvals. I have edit permissions, but review queues are apparently slow today, and I cannot make some necessary edits because a second person needs to approve the edit I want to do anyway, because someone else already suggested it.

You used to be able to [hack around this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251642/155659), which was apparently intentional, but no longer works.

> This is by design [...] a suggested edit should not block the edit of a user who has editing privileges

Can we restore the ability of users to edit things by themselves even if there's a pending edit?

I see why it requires two votes to lessen the impact of mindlessly approving through the queue, but if you're on the post directly clicking "Edit" I think anyone with edit permissions should be able to unilaterally do that.

Comment: That's what Improve Edit is for, you can edit the suggested edit and submit it. You have to go there via the suggested edits review.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard it's still pending review (at the time of writing)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Sadly once you approved, there is indeed no way to edit it until the review is completed. However, in the future you can Improve right from the popup window, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni62K.png).