# Why does this question not have an "edit" button?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I am not seeing an edit button on this question: [I'm making a program which needs to make a division by 10, but it throws Floating Point Error (ignore the spanish)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751949/im-making-a-program-which-needs-to-make-a-division-by-10-but-it-throws-floatin) (I wanted to add a "nasm" tag.) This is on Mozilla Firefox 68.0.2 on Android 9, both in the native (mobile) view as well as the "Request Desktop Site" view.

I already read [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) but the top answer says:

> In most cases, you will still see the edit button, but you will get an error message if you try to click it. However, in case 5 above, no edit button will be shown,

And point 5 is:

> You are not logged in and the post is less than 10 minutes old, or you are trying to edit a tag wiki.

Comment: There's a pending edit reviewed ATM.

Comment: That's point 4 of the linked answer. "There is a pending suggested edit to the post you're trying to edit that hasn't been reviewed yet." However, the answer doesn't say that there's no edit button in that case.

Comment: I can't tell how it renders for low rep. I can see the edit link.

Comment: There is no longer a pending edit. If you now see the edit button again we should edit the linked answer you point to.

Comment: The mobile version of the site just doesn't show an 'edit' link, instead of graying it out.

Comment: @Luuklag: Yes I do see the edit button now.